# How to add an application to the dock

Tags: dock

I'm using the Descent MATE.
How to add an application to the dock on the left side of the desktop in trouble without knowing.
If you know how to add an application to the dock, thank you for your professor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by:

Hovering over Applications > right click Applications > Edit menus

---

If not then you're most probably referring to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474421/mate-menu-is-not-configurable

Comment: I received your reply, thank you.
Hovering over Applications> right click Applications
When I make this operation, the application is launched.
It does not seem to solve the problem in this way.
Thank you.